# Enverse Lehmer's totient problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $m$ be a square free number
m is not eqale to 1 
and m is not prime
  $m=p_1 p_2\cdots p_n$

Then $m+1$ doesn't divide $(p_1+1)(p_2+1)\cdots(p_n+1)$

Is this true

Comment: Can you give context or attempts how you thought to tackle the problem?

Comment: Lehmer's totient problem   when m is square free and isn't prime   tell us that m-1 is not multiple of (p1-1)*(p2-1)......(pn-1)

Comment: http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lehmer%27s_totient_problem